# C# PowerShell Cmdlet input prompt

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Could anyone please provide a C# code sample showing how to prompt for user input in a custom PowerShell Cmdlet?

I find plenty of articles on how to pass parameters to a Cmdlet, but little to none on how to prompt for user input during runtime.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here: [MSDN ReadHostCommand Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.readhostcommand(v=vs.85).aspx)